MOSFET Not Switching On in Series-Parallel Battery Configuration Circuit
I am working on a battery management circuit that switches a set of Li-ion batteries between parallel and series configurations. To implement this, I have used six IRFZ44NPBF MOSFETs, which are controlled via half-bridge drivers (IR2104STRPBF).

Problem:
Out of the three MOSFETs in the series line, the first two switches as expected, but the final MOSFET (circled in the attached schematic) does not turn on during the transition to the series configuration.

The setup includes 1N4148 diodes for protection and gate resistors of 10kΩ and 1kΩ. I have checked the gate signals from the driver IC, and they seem to be reaching the MOSFETs correctly. I have also inspected the PCB for shorts or bad connections and measured the gate voltages. However, the final MOSFET still does not switch on, even though it receives the necessary gate voltage (12V). Could there be an issue with the timing or voltage levels from the driver IC? Are there specific design considerations for the final MOSFET in this configuration, or could there be a flaw in the driver circuit design preventing proper switching? I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

"However, the final MOSFET still does not switch on, even though it receives the necessary gate voltage (12V)"
Measured against what?
Is your high side gate driver capable of shifting the voltage up far enough to compensate for the 3x 4V offset from the three batteries below it?

"1N4148 diodes for protection" I only see 1N4148 used as bootstrap diode for your high side drivers. Please clarify.

It's the gate-source voltage that determines whether a MOSFET is on, not just the gate voltage.

Is the parallel mode for charging without cell balancing required?

@mow No, it doesn’t have the capability to shift the voltage up far enough to compensate for the offset from the three batteries below it. Do you have any suggestions for a suitable driver circuit that would work effectively for this application?

@winny you're correct. The 1N4148 diodes are indeed used as bootstrap diodes for the high-side drivers rather than for direct protection. Thank you for catching that.

@CarlRutschow Thanks! I'll check the voltage between the gate and source to ensure that the gate-source voltage is sufficient for turning the MOSFET on. Do you have any suggestions for driver circuits that can effectively shift up the voltage to achieve this?"

@Jens Yes, the parallel mode is used for charging, and the series mode is used for discharging. Let me know if you think this setup may present any issues.

You separated the cells with D5, D6 and D11, which is OK, but then the first cell needs a diode as well, or you create 0.5 V difference between cell 1 and the others. Q3 and Q5 should be P-Fets to avoid your issue. I will probably write an answer later.

Please edit your question accordingly.
